# How to perform sql query on sheets of excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-office

I have two tables in excel(sheets) . One has 10,000 entries , another has 1000 entries . Both of them have account number column in common . I want to select only those row in 10,000 entries which have their account numbers specified in 1000 entries table. An easy way is preferred .

Comment: You can filter on these records using advanced filter, just select the column with the 1000 account numbers together with the header and ensure the header names match in both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use advance filter as stated in the comments.

1. Go to: Data -> Sort & Filter -> Advanced
2. Select Filter the list, in-place
3. Select the 10,000 list account numbers as `List range`
4. Select the 1,000 list account numbers as `Criteria range`

That should provide the list you are looking for. No sql needed.